# Using urllib2 in Python, can I specify how many lines into the document it iterates before sampling input?

Tags: python, text-files, readfile

I have a Python assignment that revolves around testing various drills and tasks using the free Gutenberg library to analyze a text, **The Call of the Wild,** by Jack London.  According to Gutenberg's policy, there's a license terms information both before and after the actual contents of the book.

The assignment I have involves having to read lines and count the amount of vocals and other miscellaneous stuff, but with the licence terms being read into the script will mean that I'll read more lines than I ought to.

Is there anyway I can use liburl2 module to specify when it should begin reading in the lines(after, say, 20000 characters) and to close the file-reading process after, say, 300 000 characters are read in? This way, I'll avoid including the licence terms, and my answers won't be faulty.

The file is here: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/215/pg215.txt

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not really "using urllib2" to specify it, but `response.read()[20000:320000]`. But rather than hard-coding the offsets you should probably search for specific text that marks the start and end of the real content: it'll still work if there are minor edits to the text.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you very much.